# Model Event not working

Tags: events, laravel, model, laravel-4

I have the following model:

```
class ProjectTwitterStatus extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'project_twitter_statuses';

    protected $softDelete = true;

    protected $guarded = array('id');

    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        ProjectTwitterStatus::deleting(function($projectTwitterStatus)
        {
            $projectTwitterStatus->deleted_by = Auth::user()->id;
        });
    }

    public function twitterStatus() {
        return $this->belongsTo('TwitterStatus');
    }

    public function twitterRetweet() {
        return $this->belongsTo('TwitterRetweet','twitter_status_id','twitter_status_id');
    }

    public function project() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Project');
    }
}
```

Somewhere in my app an item is deleted using one of the following statements:

```
ProjectTwitterStatus::find($id)->delete();
ProjectTwitterStatus::whereIn('twitter_status_id', $twitterStatusIds)->delete();
```

I can see in the database the item had been (soft) deleted. But the deleted_by column is not filled.

Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try putting parent::boot() AFTER the ProjectTwitterStatus::deleting() function - does that solve it?

Comment: for deleted_by you can try my solution https://github.com/fico7489/laravel-revisionable-upgrade

Answer (score 1):

Try using [Late Static Binding](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php), like following-

```
class ProjectTwitterStatus extends Eloquent {

    public static function boot ()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::deleting(function($projectTwitterStatus)
        {
            $projectTwitterStatus->deleted_by = Auth::user()->id;
        });
    }

}
```